# Is there a way to flush cached rbac items in Yii2 with yii\rbac\PhpManager?

Tags: php, caching, yii, yii2, rbac

Yii2 has `PhpAuthManager` to set, store and check rbac items. It is cached and after I changed rights I can flush the cache completely to make new rights apply. But I would like to flush only the part of a cache with rbac items, not all of it. Is there a way to explicitly flush RBAC cache in Yii2?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on caching system. Usually the flush() method invalidates all existing items but you can use delete($key) to delete specific item. So can you provide details about cache system?

Comment: How can it depend on the caching system? I'm just using `Yii::$app->cache`. On production it uses Memcache. `PhpAuthManager` is a ready to use Yii component and somehow manages cache by itself so I of course don't know the keys to delete. Are you sure you understand the question?

Comment: In your config file should be something like: 'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\ApcCache',
    ],
] Anyway common solution for your issue is adding prefix to keys and then delete only keys with that prefix

Comment: And I saw PhpAuthManager only in Yii 1.*, in Yii2 it is called 'yii\rbac\PhpManager'

Comment: Sorry, I ment yii\rbac\PhpManager. PhpManager picks up the key by itself, without my code, I don't choose the keys unless I inherit from it and override somethng.

Comment: Yes, you have to override a few methods in child class, because there isn't functionality which you asked.